# require whitespace in first group regex

Tags: php, regex

In the process of writing a custom little template engine I want to match a block like

```
{foreach foo as bar}
    {bar.name}
{endforeach}

//with regex
preg_match_all('/{(?!{)([\w\s]+)}(?!})(.*?){(?!{)(\w+)}(?!})/us', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

So the first group must have alnum and whitespace chars with `[\w\s]+`
the negative lookahead `(?!{)` is to not allow blocks that start with `{{`

```
//so a block like 
{{foreach bla as bla}}
//would not be matched.
```

The problem is that this regex also matches `{var}` without whitespace.
And this is what I dont understand due to my first class definition 
of `[\w\s]+`

Comment: `[\w\s]+` means you match 1 or more either word *or* whitespace chars. There is no obligation to match whitespace *and* word chars.

Comment: I thought it matches both whitespace and word chars ? ..... thing is I also tried `[\w]+[\s]+` and `\w+\s+` without brackest ...also not working

Comment: You can use `\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)+\s*` to require at least 2 words with obligatory whitespace in between them. See https://regex101.com/r/V75R1k/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ... thanks this works perfect ... could you explain the `(?:` part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match at least 2 word char sequences separated with at least 1 whitespace, and allow leading and trailing whitespaces, you may use

```
\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)+\s*
```

In details:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group that is used for *grouping* subpattern sequences*:

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `)+` - 1 or more occurrences of the group
- `\s*` - trailing 0+ whitespace chars.

The entire regex will look like

```
{(?!{)(\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)+\s*)}(?!})(.*?){(?!{)(\w+)}(?!})
```

See the [updated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V75R1k/2)